# How to read in individual characters from txt.file in C++?

Tags: c++, input, command-line-arguments

I have a txt file that contains individual characters line by line. I am kind of confused as to how to read that line by line when the getline function takes in string?

Also would it be possible to store char in a vector? Or would it still work if I stored those individual characters as strings?

Comment: There is an overloaded `operator>>` for `ifstream` for `char`, have you tried that?

Comment: Be aware that **StackOverflow is not a do-my-homework website**

Answer (score -3):

code show as below:

```
vector<char> res;
int count = 0;

ifstream fin;
fin.open("***.txt");
string str;
while (!fin.eof())
{
   getline(fin, str);
   res[count++] = str;
}
fin.close();
```

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) Also, this is needlessly complicated, since you can easily do `fin >> std::noskipws/std::skipws >> yourCharVariable` and then push that to a vector. *Also*, you don't make `count` 0 after each time the loop runs, which might be an issue.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if this is right at all. How do you index a vector when it is empty? and OP specifically asked to do this `char` by `char` instead of a whole line, which this does not do.

Comment: `res[count++] = str;` accesses the vector out of bounds. `push_back` is the correct method. No need for `count` then since the size of the vector is available.